# EditForm - "Requires a Model Parameter, or an EditConext parameter, please provide one of these"

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, mudblazor, blazor-editform

I'm working on Creating a Simple Sign Up page using Blazor and MudBlazor that I can eventually pass user information as a JSON object to my server project. Being new to Blazor I opted to use the EditForm Method since it's a Blazor component and not specific to MudBlazor.

I followed the documentation here: https://mudblazor.com/components/form#editform-support

And when I navigate to my sign in page, I get an error. `EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.`

The extensive research I've done insists that the object is not being instantiated correctly, but I am nearly positive I have done this correctly. I separated my files into a ModelView, and a CodeBehind page, but even when I created everything in a single Code Block I get the same result. Here is the code

### SignUp.Razor

```
<EditForm SignUpVM="@MySignUpVM" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="7">
        <MudCard>
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudTextField Label="First name" HelperText="Max. 8 characters"
                              @bind-Value="MySignUpVM.Username" For="@(() => MySignUpVM.Username)"/>
                <MudTextField Label="Email" Class="mt-3"
                              @bind-Value="MySignUpVM.EmailAddress" For="@(() => MySignUpVM.EmailAddress)"/>
                <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Choose a strong password" Class="mt-3"
                              @bind-Value="MySignUpVM.Password" For="@(() => MySignUpVM.Password)" InputType="InputType.Password"/>
                <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Repeat the password" Class="mt-3"
                              @bind-Value="MySignUpVM.ConfPassword" For="@(() => MySignUpVM.ConfPassword)" InputType="InputType.Password"/>
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" DisableElevation="true" Class="mx-2" Link="/signin">Back</MudButton>
                <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Register</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

### SignUp.razor.cs

```
using Client.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

namespace Client.Pages
{
    public partial class SignUp : ComponentBase
    {
        bool success;
        public SignUpVM MySignUpVM { get; set; } = new SignUpVM();
        public void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
        {
            success = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

### SignUpVM.cs

```
using Client.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

namespace Client.Pages
{
   public partial class SignUp : ComponentBase
    {
        bool success;
        public SignUpVM MySignUpVM { get; set; } = new SignUpVM();
        public void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
        {
            success = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W3l9.png)

[Console Output Displaying Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDKSe.png)

I am using .NET6 for this project.

Comment: `Model=@MySignUpVM` not `MySignUpVM="@MySignUpVM"` EditForm does not have a parameter called `MySignUpVM`

Comment: And `Model` should be a plain data class - your question suggests `MySignUpVM` is a component - which I think is a mistake.  Here's the source code that generated your error  - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6ac8ebc38cd43027efb4b2cbb32599befe9a6f60/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/EditForm.cs#L81-

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing. That fixed it. Appreciate the help. I wish Blazor would have given some type of error to indicate that. My bad!

Answer (score -3):

EditForm requires a Model parameter as the error clearly suggests. Just provide a model instance

```
<EditForm Model="ClassInstance" SignUpVM="@MySignUpVM" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
```